# Ruby on Rails Paperclip avatar, undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, railstutorial.org, form-for, avatar

I was on Railstutrial on chapter 7 where it tries to add user avatars.

I tried to use paperclip to let users upload their own avatar, instead of using default [book guid on using gravatar](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#sec-a_gravatar_image) in railstutorial, chapter 7.
So I found [this tutrial](http://www.reinventar.com/2009/03/19/upload-files-with-paperclip-on-ruby-on-rails/) and did the stuff until:
This is the DB Migration  ([timestamp]_add_attachments_avatar_to_user.rb)

```
class AddAttachmentsAvatarToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :users, :avatar_file_name, :string
    add_column :users, :avatar_content_type, :string
    add_column :users, :avatar_file_size, :integer
    add_column :users, :avatar_updated_at, :datetime
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :users, :avatar_updated_at
    remove_column :users, :avatar_file_name
    remove_column :users, :avatar_content_type
    remove_column :users, :avatar_file_size
  end
end
```

This is UsersController (users_controller.rb)

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to My Site"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

This is User Model (user.rb)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation,
                  :avatar,
                  :avatar_file_name,
                  :avatar_content_type,
                  :avatar_file_size,
                  :avatar_updated_at
  has_secure_password
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :large => "120x120>", :medium => "48x48>", :thumb => "26x26>" }
  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i  
  validates :email, presence: true,
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
end
```

This is Routes file (routes.rb)

```
FinalProject::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  root to: 'static_pages#home'
  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  match '/terms',   to: 'static_pages#terms'
end
```

This is the form in my view (new.html.erb) **Updated**

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for @user, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
  
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  
      <%= f.label 'avatar' %>
      <%= f.file_field :avatar %>

      <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

and finally this is the error, when I try to signup a new user:

> **NoMethodError in Users#new**
>
> Showing /home/[username]/rails_projects/final_project/app/views/users/new.html.erb where line #6 raised:
>
> undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Please Help!

---

**UPDATED**

This is the form helper the auther proposed on reinventar.com:

```
<% form_for :user, @user, :url => user_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
```

Where as I decided to use this:

```
<%= form_for @user, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
```

I Think this should be the source of conflict!

---

**UPDATED**

As I added th `:url => user_path` to the form_for helper, now It is giving me the following error:

> **Routing Error**
> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}

I think It can not go to user page after posting form data to server!

Comment: It seems `@user` variable is `nil` when you call `form_for`. Are you sure you don't set this variable to `nil` somewhere?

Comment: like where?!! please address somewhere special so that I could take a look. I am sure I just did step by step what the rails tutorial mentioned, except thing above.

Comment: What is in 6th line of `new.html.erb`?

Comment: The form_for helper (<%= form_for @user, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %> )

Comment: What is above 6th line?

Comment: I will edit the original post inserting the whole new.html.erb file :)

Comment: Try to add `:url => user_path` as it is told in reinventar.com and Paperclip Docs (https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)

Comment: I added the :url => user_path and after that I got a Routing Error (undefined method `has_attached_file' for #<Class:0xa0d3cc0>) at first refresh. and at the second page refresh I got another Routing Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}) which persists with further more refreshes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `users_path`, not `user_path`

**EDIT**

```
users_path        =>  /users     # This URL gets routed to users#create for a
                                 # POST method and users#index for a GET method

user_path(@user)  =>  /users/55  # This URL gets routed to users#show for a GET
                                 # method and users#destroy for a DELETE method
```